# Tangent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I am confused with the idea of tangent vector or tangent space. First
of all, I learned that there is an isomorphism from $ \mathbb{R}_a^n$
onto $T_a( \mathbb{R} ^n)$ from John M.Lee' book *Introduction to
Smooth Manifolds*. Although we have the perspective of regarding
tangent vectors as an operator defined on $\mathbb{R} ^n$ or more
generally, a manifolds, I am still have trouble with it.
Again, on Lee's book,

> For example, any geomantic tangent vector $v_a \in \mathbb{R} _a^n$
>   yields a map $D_{v,a}:C^\infty ( \mathbb{R} ^n)\to \mathbb{R} $, which
>   takes the directional derivative in the direction $v$ at $a$:
>   $$D_{v,a}f = D_v f(a) = \frac{d}{dt} f(a+tv)$$

Here are my questions: Now considering a special manifold, a surface
embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the tangent of the surface.  I know
we have to define a smooth function $f$ on the (special) manifold and
we must define a function $f$ with **three** dimensions in order to take
directional derivative by a **three** dimensional vector $v_a$. However,
our manifold is a **two** dimensional surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}
^3$. Unfortunately, $2\neq 3$. So, what's dimension of the domain of
$f$ with respect to the special manifold?

**Edit**:@Jack Lee: He points out that tangent vectors to the sphere are defined more abstractly as derivations. At first we have Euclidean space,$\mathbb{R}^3$, and the space $\mathbb{R}_a^n$, so we have its tangent space $T_p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and we prove that these two linear vector space are isomorphic. We then define the general tangent space w.r.t manifolds.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $p$ be a point of $M$. A linear map $v:C^\infty(M)\to R$ is called a derivation at $p$ if it satisfies $$v(fg) = f(p)vg + g(p)vg$$ for all $f,g \in C^\infty(M)$. The set of all derivation of $C^\infty(M)$ at $p$, denoted by $T_p M$, is a vector space called the tangent space to $M$ at $P$. An element of $T_p M$ is called a tangent vector at $p$.

The author then discuss the sub-manifolds and the relation between the tangent space of the embedding space and its ambient space.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $S\subseteq M$ be an immersed or embedded submanifold. Since the inclusion map $\iota:\hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth immersion, at each point $p\in S$ we have in injective linear map $d_{\iota_p}:T_p S\to T_p M$. In terms of derivations, this injection works in the following way: for any vector $v\in T_p S$, the pimage vector $\tilde{v} = d_{\iota_p}(v)\in T_p M$ acts on smooth functions on $M$ by $$\tilde{v}f = d_{\iota_p}(v)f = v(f\cdot\iota) = v(f\big|_S)$$

Finally, there is also a picture illustrated on the book help a lot.
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly is your doubt? If possible, depending minimally on the image?

Comment: The notation $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^n)$ means the space of all infinitely differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I delete the picture for short. my question is the last question. what's the dimension of the domain of f.

Comment: @MarkFantini tanks a lot. i get the idea of this definition, but f is defined on the surface and the surface is not $R^3$.... isn't it restrict the domain to the surface? whatever, i don't know

Comment: Is your question *What is the definition of a smooth function from one manifold to another?"*, or *"What is the definition of the derivative of one smooth function from one manifold to another?"*. The question is still not clear to me. For instance, I don't know what relation you tried to establish between your questions and what are above them.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo thank you for your attention. I am crazy about this but i can't express my problem well. ( •̀∀•́ )  in a word, why 2 is not agree with 3 but it is still ok.

Comment: @Brooks I think your problem resides on the definitions. Try taking another book and opening it. Some times when we get stuck in a book, finding another point of view helps. I would gladly help, but I really don't understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo for the definition of smooth function from one abstrct manifold to another,  i know them well, but i am confused with the smooth function defined on the special manifolds which embedding in Euclid space.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo i read another book such as Loring W.Tu 's an introduction to manifolds, but the problems are still in my mind. For the speacial manifold, do we define smooth function in the surface or in $R^3$?

Comment: thanks all of you. i try to take it easy and have a rest at first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're trying to read more into this definition than is there. The definition you quoted is *only* talking about tangent vectors to $\mathbb R^n$, not to submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ such as the sphere. Tangent vectors to the sphere are defined more abstractly as derivations (see p. 54). The relationship between tangent vectors to $\mathbb R^n$ and tangent vectors to a submanifold like the sphere isn't developed until Chapter 5.

Comment: thank you so much. you really help me a lot. It is the second edition of this book, isn't it. I will read those material. I choose your answer for the best answer. thx

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the second edition. If you have the first edition, tangent vectors to manifolds are defined on p. 65, and the relationship with tangent vectors to $\mathbb R^n$ is discussed in Chapter 8.